# What type of lock (table hint) to use for this?

Tags: sql, concurrency, locking, rdbms

Say I have two columns CategoryId and SubcategoryId. SubcategoryId starts from 1 for each CategoryId. When inserting a new subcategory I need to calculate MAX(SubcategoryId)+1 for the given CategoryId.

Is the following correct?

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
DECLARE @NextId bigint;
SELECT @NextId = ISNULL(MAX(SubcategoryId),0) + 1 
FROM Subcategory WITH (UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK) 
WHERE CategoryId = @CategoryId;
INSERT INTO Subcategory
(
    CategoryId, 
    SubcategoryId
) 
VALUES
(
    @CategoryId, 
    @NextId
 );
COMMIT
```

Does WITH(UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK) also prevent concurrent insertions of new rows with the same CategoryId or does it only lock the exiting rows that matched at the time of the SELECT? If it's the latter should I change it to a TABLOCK? Is some kind of exclusive lock required too?

Comment: Could you please post the table definitions. It will help a lot as you might not need to do this and just a simple identity.

Comment: The table is very simple. Subcategory(CategoryId bigint, SubcategoryId bigint) and a unique key composed of both columns so that SubcategoryId can repeat for a different CategoryId.

Comment: Added a possible answer for you.

Comment: The code I originally posted above is the correct solution. The UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK prevents any new records with the same CategoryId being inserted.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking it is NOT recommended to mess with locking levels unless you have a very particular requirement. From my understanding there is a way for your concurrency issue to be handled by SQL server engine without locking hints.

So your table definition is:

```
CREATE TABLE Subcategory
(
   CategoryId bigint, 
   SubcategoryId bigint
 )
```

If you change the table definition to:

```
CREATE TABLE Subcategory
(
   CategoryId bigint NOT NULL, 
   SubcategoryId bigint IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
 ) ON [PRIMARY];
 ALTER TABLE Subcategory
 ADD CONSTRAINT pk_Subcategory PRIMARY KEY (CategoryId,SubcategoryId  )
```

SubcategoryID will become a autonumber. This number will increment on each insert. Thus you dont need to specify the subcategoryid during your insert this will allow SQL server to take care of the concurrency. It is best to let SQL handle the locking of tables and deal with concurrency.

If you change your table structure to what I suggested your query becomes simpler as well.

```
BEGIN TRAN
INSERT INTO Subcategory
(
    CategoryId, 

) 
VALUES
(
    @CategoryId, 

 );
 COMMIT TRAN
```

This might be a solution for you. Sorry my syntax might be wrong as I have not touched SQL server in months.

Comment: Both CategoryId and SubcategoryId are already Identity values generated and stored in other master tables. This table simply groups subcategories under categories. After further reading about various kinds of locking, I've determined that my original proposal is the only completely safe solution.